# Avoiding global variables in Python as a new programmer

Tags: python, variables, global

I'm just getting started with Python, working my way through LPtHW. I'm on exercise 36 which has you designing your own game. I'm trying to make a very basic game, but am having trouble avoiding global variables. For example, for fighting a monster it checks to see if you have a sword. Currently I do this by first creating the global variable sword at the beginning 
sword = 0, then when you obtain the sword its value is changed to one, then when you fight the monster you win if global sword == 1. How can I change my coding to avoid using a global variable?

Comment: Look into objects, classes, and attributes.

Comment: In your game you have entities like monster, the player and the game field. Think about what a monster could have or your player could have as attributes. After that, try to write a python class that models the structure that you've defined.
Once you have class, you can create some object that can interacts each other.
Post here some code in order to receive some tips from the community

Comment: Just wanted to echo the recommendations to look into object oriented programming (objects and etc). Also that it's a GREAT thing that you're mindful of best practices early, rather than trying to change the way you code later. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Using classes is the main way of avoiding the use of global variables.

For example, instead of  declaring a global variable for *sword* at the start of your program, you could create a *Player* class with an attribute which represents whether or not the player has a sword.

In this class, you could then create a method which returns whether or not the player has a sword, avoiding ever using a variable outside of the class *Player*.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, sword):
        self.sword = sword
    def playerHasSword():
        return self.sword
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a very simplistic class ... (including fighting!!!)

```
import random
class PlayerKilled(Exception): #player died
     pass #just a mechanism to detect killing a player

DAMAGE_TABLE = { #how much damage for weapons
   "MACE":6,
   "SWORD":8,
   "DAGGER":5,
   "FISTS":3
}
class MOB:
    def __init__(self,name,hp,weapon="FISTS"):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.ac = 3 # defense
        self.level = 1
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.dead = False
    def battle(self,MOB2):
        attacker,defender = self, MOB2
        if random.random() > 0.5:
            print "%s Attacks First!"%MOB2.name
            attacker,defender = defender,attacker
        while not self.dead and not MOB2.dead:
            attacker.attack(defender)
            attacker,defender = defender,attacker
        return defender
    def attack(self,MOB2):
        dmg = sum(random.randint(1,DAMAGE_TABLE[self.weapon]) for _ in range(self.level))
        print "%s Attacks with %s for %s DMG!"%(self.name,self.weapon,dmg)
        try:
           MOB2.defend(dmg)
        except PlayerKilled:
           print "%s has killed %s"%(self.name,MOB2.name)

    def defend(self,dmg):
        if sum(random.randint(0,self.ac) for _ in range(self.level)) > dmg:
            print "%s blocks the attack"%self.name
            return 
        self.hp = self.hp - dmg
        if self.hp < 0:
            print "%s has died!"%self.name
            self.hp = 0
            self.dead = True
            raise PlayerKilled

p1 = MOB("player",20,"DAGGER")
p2 = MOB("vampire",20,"FISTS")
winner = p1.battle(p2)
print "%s WINS with %s HP left!"%(winner.name,winner.hp)
```